# Question about Subject–auxiliary inversion

Tags: verbs, nouns, subjects

Is this sentence correct?

> I enjoy motivating the students and helping them understand that they learn as much from making mistakes as they do a perfect score.

Comment: Which part do you think is related to subject-auxiliary inversion?

Comment: 'I received as much from Jane as John' is short for 'I received as much from Jane as John did', not 'I received as much from Jane as I did from John'. The second 'from' needs to be retained. And to avoid faulty parallelism, 'I enjoy motivating the students and helping them understand that they learn as much from making mistakes as they do from achieving a perfect score.' is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very close to correct. All you have to do is add *from*.

> I enjoy motivating the students and helping them understand that they learn as much from making mistakes as they do from a perfect score.

Otherwise it sounds as if they are making the mistakes while they do a perfect score.

Comment: 'Question about Subject–auxiliary inversion.' Correcting the given sentence is unrelated, and unsuitable for ELU.